# Sorting a Python list using two criteria

Tags: python, dictionary

I am sorting a list using 2 criteria:

```
index_sort = {'r1':1, 'r2':2, 'T1':3, 'r3':4, 'T2':5, 'T3':6}

Eall_pairsorted = sorted(Eall_pairsorted, key = lambda e: (index_sort[e[0]], index_sort2[e[1]]  ))
```

The issue is that I am getting:

```
['r1', 'r2', '++', '0.01 0.01', -56.19568267]
['r1', 'T1', '++', '0.01 0.017453292519943295', -56.19567285]
['r1', 'r3', '++', '0.01 0.01', -56.19568267]
['r1', 'T2', '++', '0.01 0.017453292519943295', -56.19567285]
['r1', 'T3', '++', '0.01 0.017453292519943295', -56.19568714]
['r2', 'T1', '++', '0.01 0.017453292519943295', -56.19567439]
['r2', 'r3', '++', '0.01 0.01', -56.19568267]
['r2', 'T2', '++', '0.01 0.017453292519943295', -56.1956784]
['r2', 'T3', '++', '0.01 0.017453292519943295', -56.19568357]
['T1', 'T2', '++', '0.017453292519943295 0.017453292519943295', -56.19566509]
['T1', 'T3', '++', '0.017453292519943295 0.017453292519943295', -56.19570279]
['r3', 'T1', '++', '0.01 0.017453292519943295', -56.1956784]
['r3', 'T2', '+-', '0.01 0.017453292519943295', -56.19567944]
['r3', 'T3', '++', '0.01 0.017453292519943295', -56.19568357]
['r3', 'T3', '--', '0.01 0.017453292519943295', -56.19568081]
['r3', 'T3', '+-', '0.01 0.017453292519943295', -56.19569063]
['r3', 'T3', '-+', '0.01 0.017453292519943295', -56.1956905]
['T2', 'T3', '++', '0.017453292519943295 0.017453292519943295', -56.19570279]
['T2', 'T3', '--', '0.017453292519943295 0.017453292519943295', -56.19570039]
['T2', 'T3', '+-', '0.017453292519943295 0.017453292519943295', -56.195661]
['T2', 'T3', '-+', '0.017453292519943295 0.017453292519943295', -56.19566132]
```

and I want to have switched r3 and T1 in a line:

```
   ['r3', 'T1', '++', '0.01 0.017453292519943295', -56.1956784]
```

to get the following order:

```
['T1', 'r3', '++', '0.01 0.017453292519943295', -56.1956784]
```

I only want to swap 'T1' and 'r3', not a whole column.

Any tips how to do it?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? i.e. removing unnecessary data, using more readable variable names, etc.

Comment: So basically you just want to swap the first and second elements in each list around? What has that got to do with sorting? If you want the sorting to be applied with the variables in their flipped position, either flip them before you sort or else change the order of the indices in your `key` lambda function. i.e `lambda e: (index_sort[e[1]], index_sort2[e[0]])`

Comment: Do you want to swap only entries with `r3` and `T1` or the whole column?

Comment: Yes, only r3 and T1

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it at the same time as sorting, but you can do something like this afterwards:

```
Eall_pairsorted = sorted(Eall_pairsorted, key = lambda e: (e[0], e[1]))
Eall_pairsorted = [[e[1], e[0]] + e[2:] for e in Eall_pairsorted]
```

Test:

```
>>> Eall_pairsorted = [
...     ['r1', 'r2', '++', '0.01 0.01', -56.19568267],
...     ['r1', 'T1', '++', '0.01 0.017453292519943295', -56.19567285],
...     ['r1', 'r3', '++', '0.01 0.01', -56.19568267]
... ]
>>> Eall_pairsorted = [[e[1], e[0]] + e[2:] for e in Eall_pairsorted]
>>> Eall_pairsorted
[
    ['r2', 'r1', '++', '0.01 0.01', -56.19568267], 
    ['T1', 'r1', '++', '0.01 0.017453292519943295', -56.19567285], 
    ['r3', 'r1', '++', '0.01 0.01', -56.19568267]
]
```

Comment: It is not right. it messed up first elements as I am getting in return: 'r2', 'r1', 'T1', 'r1', 'r3', 'r1' and so forth

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question then. Please check the test example, is it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want to rearrange the first two elements in the list in this specific case? Or which general rule do you want to be applied here? I think you should really clarify your question. If there is only one specific case that is bothering you, the following will work.

With list comprehension:

```
lst = [
    ['r1', 'r2', '++', '0.01 0.01', -56.19568267],
    ['r3', 'T1', '++', '0.01 0.017453292519943295', -56.19567285],
    ['r1', 'r3', '++', '0.01 0.01', -56.19568267]]

lst = [['T1', 'r3'] + x[2:] if x[0:2] == ['r3', 'T1'] else x for x in lst]
```

Without list comprehension:

```
Eall_pairsorted = [
    ['r1', 'r2', '++', '0.01 0.01', -56.19568267],
    ['r3', 'T1', '++', '0.01 0.017453292519943295', -56.19567285],
    ['r1', 'r3', '++', '0.01 0.01', -56.19568267]]

for index, item in enumerate(Eall_pairsorted):
    if item[0:2] == ['r3', 'T1']:
        Eall_pairsorted[index][0:2] = ['T1', 'r3']
```